# How do I find the AWS Quicksight IP Range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm looking to allow connections from [AWS Quicksight](https://quicksight.aws) to my PostgreSQL database.

And in their [FAQ](https://quicksight.aws/faq/) they offer some advice that Quicksight has a dedicated IP range

```
Q: How do I connect my VPC to Amazon QuickSight?

If your VPC has been set up with public connectivity, 
you can add Amazon QuickSight’s IP address range to your database 
instances’ security group rules to enable traffic flow into your VPC 
and database instances.
```

But in the AWS IP Ranges JSON file (https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) there is no mention of the AWS Quicksight range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QuickSight's IP address ranges are as follow:

Region- IP Range

US East (N. Virginia) (us-east-1)- 52.23.63.224/27

US West (Oregon) (us-west-2)- 54.70.204.128/27

EU (Ireland) (eu-west-1)- 52.210.255.224/27

We're in the process of adding it to the ip-ranges.json file.

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL 2016 instance inside a VPC from quick sight as well. I've opened the `1433` port to all _any_ IP in the windows firewall. Then opened the 1433 port to the range Luis gave for `eu-west-1` in the security group but I still can't connect. BTW when I open the 1433 port to any IP I still can't connect from quick sight. I'm trying to connect to the server using its pubic IP. Could I be overlooking the obvious?

Comment: Hi bounav, there is a known issue with connecting to SQL server that is currently being fixed. I expect we will be able to deploy a fix in the next day or two.

Comment: @LuisWang The connectivity issue only applies to MySQL? I am having problem connecting to PostgresRDS instance. All I get is non-descriptive error message `Connection failed, check connection information`

Answer (score 1):

AWS published the IP ranges here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/regions.html